# cd: "No such file or directory" after setting a variable

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc

```
$ export AMBERHOME=$AMBERHOME/home/rcibsd/amber14
$ cd $AMBERHOME
bash: cd: /home/rcibsd/home/rcibsd/amber14::/home/rcibsd/amber14:/home/rcibsd/amber14:/home/rcibsd/amber14:/home/rcibsd/amber14:/home/rcibsd/amber14: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Close Voters, "unclear what you're asking"? What is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$AMBERHOME` contains an invalid folder name. Therefore the command `cd` can't work.

Every time you run the command `export AMBERHOME=$AMBERHOME/home/rcibsd/amber14`, `AMBERHOME` will be set to the old value of `AMBERHOME` **and** the string `/home/rcibsd/amber14`

*Example*

```
% FOO="/bar"
% FOO="$FOO/bar"
% FOO="$FOO/bar"
% FOO="$FOO/bar"
% echo $FOO     
/bar/bar/bar/bar
```

---

*Your special solution ;c)*

1. Edit the file `.bashrc`

   ```
   nano ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add this line at the end of the file

   ```
   export AMBERHOME="/home/rcibsd/amber14"
   ```
3. Save and close

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd>
4. Open a new terminal
5. Check the result

   ```
   echo $AMBERHOME
   ```

   <sub>Should be `/home/rcibsd/amber14`</sub>

   ```
   cd $AMBERHOME
   ```

   <sub>Should simply work</sub>

Comment: bashrc file was added with export AMBERHOME=$AMBERHOME/home/rcibsd/amber14 Temporarily it shows the path when typed cd $AMBERHOME but on reboot it doesnt, please suggest permanent setup. When I tried gksudo to edit the bashrc file, it shows the PATH however a message comes "No such file or directory".

Comment: I don't know, what Amber is.

Comment: @Sunil And as I said in my answer: `export AMBERHOME="/home/rcibsd/amber14"`

Comment: Dear AB, I am new to Linux, I want to set AMBERHOME environment variable and I tried doing export AMBERHOME=/home/rcibsd/amber14. It works when I type cd $AMBERHOME, it shows PATH /rcibsd/amber14. But on reboot it dissapears. Hence I tried again to do it permanently by editing bashrc file in gksudo gedit command and now  though it shows the PATH in repeats BUT also says No such file or directory. I tried your command as well but results are same.

Comment: @Sunil =) See my improved answer :)

Comment: @Sunil As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! **;-)**

Comment: By mistake I set PATH and now could not execute any command - The command was export PATH="/home/rcibsd/ngs"  Now its not even accepting nano ~/.bashrc command .... how to change it ?

Comment: @Sunil `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`. Open the editor with `/usr/bin/nano ~/.bashrc`

Comment: rcibsd@server:~$ gedit /usr/bin/nano ~/.bashrc
Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
gedit: command not found

Comment: ok, maybe `gedit`, nano is only a command line editor. Use gedit with this command `/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc`